# To store collectons of collections in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I will like to store a collection of collection in the neo4j, but it is giving me an error so is there any other way.

Query:

```
CREATE (d:Dummy {property:[null,null,null,[23,32,23],null,null,[23,23,23]}) RETURN d
```

Error: Collections containing null values can not be stored in properties.

So how to solve this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your collection violates at least these 2 neo4j constraints:

- Properties cannot store collections containing `null` values.
- Properties cannot store collections with nested collections.

If you *really* need to store such collections, one workaround is to store the collection in *stringified* JSON format. For example:

```
CREATE (d:Dummy {property: '[null,null,null,[23,32,23],null,null,[23,23,23]]' })
RETURN d
```

Later on, when you need to use the property value, you will need to convert it back to a neo4j collection. The `apoc.convert.fromJsonList` function can be used for that purpose. For example:

```
MATCH (d:Dummy)
RETURN apoc.convert.fromJsonList(d.property);
```